# Get all pixel array inside circle

Tags: xna

I have this:

[image]

And I need to know all pixels in array inside the circle.

Thanks.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You are looking for the following set of pixels:

[image: Circle equation]

with *r* being the radius of your circle and *(m1, m2)* the center.

In order to get these pixels iterate over all positions and store those which meet the criteria in a list:

```cs
List<int> indices = new List<int>();

for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
    {
        double dx = x - m1;
        double dy = y - m2;
        double distanceSquared = dx * dx + dy * dy;

        if (distanceSquared <= radiusSquared)
        {
            indices.Add(x + y * width);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're welcome. By the way, you can speed things up by only iterating over the pixels in the bounding rectangle of the circle.

Comment: Does approach include border pixels?

Comment: @OPV If we define a border pixel as one that satisfies (x-m1)²+(y-m2)²=r² you can include them if you check with "less than or equal" (<=) and exclude them if you check for "less than" (<).

Comment: Than how to resolve this the equation when I have two undefined variables?

Comment: @OPV There aren't any undefined variables, or equations to solve. See the code above.

Comment: This code is really amazing! Very clever!! I was wondering if there is any faster way in order to check if a randomly chosen point (pixel) in the image is inside or outside the circle without having to run through the hole image?

Comment: @just_learning Thanks, and of course there is a faster way. If you have a random point, just check it using the condition above. No iteration required.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn´t this be an more efficient approach? (Don't iterating over the whole picture, just the desired square)

```cs
List<int> indices = new List<int>();

xmin = m1 - r;
xmax = m1 + r;
ymin = m2 - r;
ymax = m2 + r;

for (int x = xmin; x < xmax ; x++)
{
    for (int y = ymin; y < ymax; y++)
    {
        double dx = x - m1;
        double dy = y - m2;
        double distanceSquared = dx * dx + dy * dy;

        if (distanceSquared <= radiusSquared)
        {
            indices.Add(x + y * width);
        }
    }
}
```